# How are Warning and Fatal alerts treated during SSLHandshake

Tags: java, ssl

I am using SSL connection and for some use I need to find out the alert type and its severity when it is thrown from the Java library.

```
sslException.getAlertLevel() or sslException.getAlertSeverity()
```

Like if the level of severity is **FATAL** I need to take some steps on it,
but I could not find from where I could get this information.

**EDIT:**

There are two Alert Levels defined in the RFC for TLS and they are **Warning** level and **Fatal** level and I need to find out which level it was.

Also if all are Fatal level I also need to find out the type of Fatal alert.
Any help would be appreciated.

Maybe the question is not asked or formed properly but what if there are some warning alerts during the handshake?

[java.dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors%20this%20link%20shows%20in%20the%20Certificate%20expiration%20section%20that%20if%20the%20certificate%20are%20expired%20still%20in%20that%20case%20java%20throws%20SSL%20Exception%20but%20it%20is%20a%20warning%20according%20to%20RFC.) this link shows in the Certificate expiration section that if the certificate are expired still in that case java throws SSL Exception but it is a warning according to RFC.

Comment: @EJP I have changed the question title to make more clear my doubt.

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors this link shows in the **Certificate expiration** section that if the certificate are expired still in that case java throws SSL Exception but it is a warning according to RFC.

Comment: `CertificateException`s (expired, not yet valid, ...) are not `SSLException`s. The article you're referring to is about an `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`, which is not a certificate exception, and which is fatal when the cipher suite requires authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All* SSLExceptions are fatal apart from `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`,<sup>1</sup> as are all SocketExceptions apart from SocketTimeoutException, and all other IOExceptions.

> 1. `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` is non-fatal in the case where you are the server and have requested but not required a client certificate.

Comment: See my edited answer, and for the cases when the certificate sent by the client is revoked and all are warning level alerts and they should not be treated as fatal

Comment: It is me who has asked the question on OTN too :) I understand what you are saying. But what about the cases when the certificate of the client is expired. In that case if the exception is not thrown is there a way to find out that information while connection is being negotiated. Because in that case some servers may treat that as fatal and close the connection.

Comment: @NarendraPathai Does JSSE throw an exception on expired certificates?

Comment: I do not know yet and trying to find that out. But what I mean to say is that there has to be some way in the API to handle warning alerts I guess. and no_renegotiation is always to be treated as Warning as per RFC 2246. At some level client or server can decide to treat a particular warning as fatal and close the connection

Comment: Sorry if I offended you in some way :) I did not mean to. I am new to using JSSE and had a case where I had to differentiate between these two alert levels. I appreciate your help. But still not clear to me completely.

Comment: @NarendraPathai None of this changes the fact that all `SSLExceptions` are fatal. That is the information you asked for. It's not available at runtime because it doesn't have to be.

Comment: We are using TLS over Diameter protocol and there I need this information

Comment: Please have a look at a link in my second comment

Comment: @NarendraPathai OK so it throws an `SSLException` for an expired certificate. So it's fatal. Please note I have added `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` as a non-fatal exception.